# How to retrieve cURL response on error in PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am using PHP 7.4/8.0 and cURL to call an API and download a large PDF file based on a user request.  Because the file is large, I don't want to use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and first save the file to a PHP string or a temp file, only to then send the file contents to the user's browser.  Instead, I want to pass the file contents directly to the user's browser, like a proxy server might do.  I am calling it with code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.example.com/api',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"item": "1"}',
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
));

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

The issue is when the API returns an error, it sends a HTTP 500 code, and in the response body, it includes the error details such as:

```
{
    "error": "111",
    "message": "This is the error message"
}
```

When an error happens, I want to catch that error in my code and handle it.  Passing CURLOPT_FAILONERROR allows me to catch the error, but I can't figure out how to get the response body that the API sent back.

Is there a way to get the response body in a scenario like this?  Again, I don't want to use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER as I want to pass the output directly through to the user's browser when there is no error.  I only want to get the response body when there is an error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Surely with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, you can in the code work out if an error has occurred.  If no error - then echo out the returned content.

Comment: Yes, `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` will work, but that will require storing the HTTP response in a PHP variable and it would be subject to `memory_limit`.  I'm trying to avoid having to save the response when there is no error.